# Onclick of Radio button listbox cant be Clear in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here i am trying to do is on on-click of radio button list-box had to display with auto-complete but its not clear  on-click ..so how to change  according to radio button and display it..with auto complete properly

```
<script>

 (function ($) {
         $.widget("custom.combobox", {
                 _create: function () {
                     this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                         .addClass("custom-combobox")
                         .insertAfter(this.element);
                     this.element.hide();
                     this._createAutocomplete();
                     this._createShowAllButton();
                 },
                 _createAutocomplete: function () {
                     var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
                         value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                     this.input = $("<input>")
                         .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                         .val(value)
                         .attr("title", "")
                         .attr("id", "sss")
                         .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
                         .autocomplete({
                             delay: 0,
                             minLength: 0,
                             source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
                         })
                         .tooltip({
                             tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                         });
                     this._on(this.input, {
                         autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                             ui.item.option.selected = true;
                             this._trigger("select", event, {
                                 item: ui.item.option
                             });
                         },
                         autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                     });
                 },
```

[Look at this link](http://jsfiddle.net/dvx53/26/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here... When you click on a radio button, a dropdown appears below, and autocomplete works. If you expect the dropdown to be empty before you start, you need to add an empty value, such as:  <option value="">Take your pick</option>

Comment: see here now am clicking maingroup dropdown display again now clicking  country its also displaying but if i click  subgroup ,maingroup drop down is not clearing and if i click item group ,subgroup and maingroup is not clearing that is my problem

Comment: You mean the dropdown doesn't disappear once you've switched from one selected option to the next? Is there a reason why you're creating new inputs with JS instead of using a show/hide behavior?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it never actually alerts "maingroup", when you select that radio button.

This means that there's something wrong with:

```
if($('input:radio[name=A]:checked').val()=="maingroup"){...}
```

and that problem is that input:radio is not a valid jquery selector.

Use this instead:

```
if($('input[name=A]:checked').val()=="maingroup"){...}
```

(you do it a couple of times throughout your code)

Check out what happens with that. If you're still having trouble, it means there's more errors... Keep your fiddle updated in that case.

Comment: fine As a beginner am learning on the way ..its possible to update my code its useful to learn from u???

Comment: Try updating your jsFiddle with this info I just gave you. Remember we're all volunteers at StackOverflow. You should always make it as easy as possible for people to help you! You're on the right track using alerts for debugging anyway, try using that further to narrow down where the error is.

Comment: [jsfiddle fiddle update link](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/dvx53/38/)  now its not a showing a drop down??

Comment: You've made the same mistake in several places. You need to correct all of them. Additionally, input:[name=B] is not valid either. It should be input[name=B]